# What is the perfect correct way to incorporate CSS and JS files from a theme into Angular8 project

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular8, package.json

Sorry If this seems trivial at first glance. But I am quite stuck! What is the absolute correct and proper way to add the various CSS and JS files from a theme into your Angular8 app project?

Let me elaborate. I have this theme which I aim to use in my Angular8 app. I tried to incorporate the relevant css js files, various ways.

- in the index.html file
- inside the app.component.html file
- in the styles and scripts array of the angular.json file

Neither worked.
This is how I did in the package.json file -

```
    blablablabla,
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "src/assets/css/style.css",
          "src/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "src/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css",
          "src/assets/css/ionicons.min.css",
          "src/assets/css/main.css",
          "src/assets/css/style.css",
          "src/assets/css/responsive.css",
          "src/assets/rs-plugin/css/settings.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
         "src/assets/js/modernizr.js",
          "src/assets/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js",
          "src/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js",
          "src/assets/js/own-menu.js",
          "src/assets/js/jquery.lighter.js",
          "src/assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js",
          "src/assets/rs-plugin/js/jquery.tp.t.min.js",
          "src/assets/rs-plugin/js/jquery.tp.min.js",
          "src/assets/js/main.js"
        ]
```

Nothing works. If I inspect the SOURCES from console, it shows none of the css or js files loaded and delivered!! I thought the last approach was at least a proper way of adding CSS JS in Angular8 project.

As you can see, I tried 3 ways and neither worked. Can you tell me the ***EXACT CORRECT WAY*** I should do it? Alternately, any edits/modifications in my 3 approaches that should suffice? Expecting some clear guidance on this.

Addition. My entire angular.json. Note I added the styles and scripts src under the 'build' section only. Can you spot the trouble area?

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "MyShop": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/MyShop",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/assets/css/style.css",
              "src/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css",
              "src/assets/css/ionicons.min.css",
              "src/assets/css/main.css",
              "src/assets/css/style.css",
              "src/assets/css/responsive.css",
              "src/assets/rs-plugin/css/settings.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "src/assets/js/modernizr.js",
              "src/assets/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js",
              "src/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "src/assets/js/own-menu.js",
              "src/assets/js/jquery.lighter.js",
              "src/assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js",
              "src/assets/rs-plugin/js/jquery.tp.t.min.js",
              "src/assets/rs-plugin/js/jquery.tp.min.js",
              "src/assets/js/main.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "MyShop:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "MyShop:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "MyShop:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/assets/css/style.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [

            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "MyShop:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "MyShop:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }},
  "defaultProject": "MyShop"
}
```

Comment: As a rule of thumb, Angular and Jquery will never work together.

Comment: That I did do, @MaihanNijat  stopped it and served it again fresh using ng serve --open.

Comment: Why do you have all those files in your `assets` folder? You can leave them (e.g. bootstrap) in `node_modules`. Read: [Angular Docs - Adding a library to the runtime global scope](https://angular.io/guide/using-libraries#adding-a-library-to-the-runtime-global-scope)

Comment: hey, what if I do a npm i of jquery and types/jquery and add import statements to the 2 in my app.component.ts to make my angular proj. use and parse jquery?       @ling-vu

Answer (score 0):

Putting your themes into the `angular.json` file is correct. But be careful, there are you places in the `angular.json` file where you have to put it. One for the build and one for the serve

```
{
  ....
  "projects": {
    "demo": {
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            ....
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          ...
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "demo:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "demo:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "demo:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {...
            "styles": [
              "styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        ...
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "demo"
}
```

Comment: Yes, I put in the upper one. There are 2 such styles[] and scripts[] regions in the file I do understand. But that did not work is the main concern!   @ling-vu

Answer (score 0):

Your Style needs to be bundle, into the general `style.css`, when you generate your app. In order to do that, you need to add them to your `angular.json` file.

Here is an example taken [from angular8-example-app on github, by Ismaestro](https://github.com/Ismaestro/angular8-example-app/blob/master/angular.json)

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "angularexampleapp": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          /* ... */
          "options": {
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.browser.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css",
              "src/assets/css/reset.css",
              "src/assets/css/loading.css",
              "src/app/shared/styles/global.scss"
            ],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "src/app/shared/styles"
              ]
            }
            /* ... */
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  /* ... */
  "defaultProject": "angularexampleapp"
}
```

See the `styles` array under `projects` → `angularexampleapp` → `architect` → `build` → `options`

Comment: Just a mo. I have got multiple inputs at the mo. Let me follow 1 by 1. In fact I will post my angular.json file if that helps to identify!              @Nicolas

Comment: It's not in the `package.json` it's in the `angular.json`. @PrabirChoudhury

Comment: @PrabirChoudhury Are you using any other bundle generator ? Because this is the only way to do so. Maybe delete the `dist` folder and try again ?

Comment: no, only webpack  @Nicolas.  ok, noted, delete the entire dist. do a fresh ng build --prod and try.